# Statements of uncertainty?

Tags: vocabulaire

In English, I like to add on certain modifiers when giving people information, so as to remind them that the information is not guaranteed to be true. Examples include:

- "In my opinion,..."
- "...but that's just my opinion."
- "So far as I know..."
- "Last I checked..."
- "Maybe it's just me."
- "I could be wrong."
- "I'm pretty sure, but not positive..."

Many of these seem sort of English-particular to me, and I feel like if I translate them literally they may be unusual statements in French. What are some casual French phrases expressing uncertainty?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You aren't short of options in French either, here are a bunch that come to my mind. I'm sure others will contribute many more:

- *Pour moi, …*
- *En ce qui me concerne, …*
- *Ce que j'en dis, c'est que…*
- *Je me trompe/plante peut-être, mais…*
- *Il me semble que…*
- *À mon avis…*
- *De ce que j'en sais, …*

Comment: Il y a aussi le paradoxal "Sans doute..."

Comment: Et aussi _« D'après moi... »_

Answer (score 6):

I would add "Pour autant que je sache" to the possible equivalents of "As far as I know".
Some people could opt to omit the "pour", although to me it sounds a bit more formal.

> As far as I know, the 64-bit version is not yet available.
>
> Pour autant que je sache, la version 64-bits n'est pas encore disponible.
>
> My life, as far as I know, is far from over !
>
> Ma vie, autant que je sache, est loin d'être terminée !

There's also a related form of "il me semble que", which is "semble-t-il". It can be thought more or less as a translation of "it seems".

> Few people, it seems, are brave enough to...
>
> Peu de gens, semble-t-il, sont suffisamment courageux pour...

I also personally use it to begin sentences :

> It seems that they already got married.
>
> Semble-t-il qu'ils se soient déjà marriés.

In this case, it is a bit more detached than "Il me semble que" : it puts on emphasis on the fact and enounces it as more of a general "truth" rather than your personal knowledge.

There's also a last one which I am particularly fond of, and which seems [quite old](http://www2.ac-lyon.fr/enseigne/lettres/louise/sonnets/viiii.html), and that is "m'est avis que". It is a bit familiar so use it as an oral-only construction.

> In my opinion, the facebook stock is grossly overvalued.
>
> M'est avis que les actions facebook sont largement surévaluées.

Answer (score 5):

Some more :

- "Moi, je dirais que..." or just "Je dirais que..."
- "Si tu veux mon avis, ..." / "Si vous voulez mon avis, ..."

And the very casual (made famous by Coluche if I'm not wrong)

- "Moi, je dis ça, je dis rien, mais..."